# How to get part of the string based on 2 delimiters?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string that looks like,

`var str = "C:\\Users\\source\\repos\\InitiateService\\InitiateService\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0\\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll"`

How should I split based on 2 delimiters such that I only get `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp`.

Tried below code

```
                            str.Split('//', '.');
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str.Replace(@"\\",@"\"));`

Comment: It didn't work. It gave the whole path as output `C:\Users\sranade\source\repos\InitiateService\InitiateService\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` except the extension and a slash @yassinMi

Comment: in what way did nt it work?

Comment: @yassinMi Pretty sure the `Replace` isn't even necessary.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel you're right

Comment: @yassinMi I need the output to be `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp`

Comment: And what is your output if you use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`?

Comment: You could do this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/a14BY2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a fairly simple way to me:

```
var str = "C:\\Users\\source\\repos\\InitiateService\\InitiateService\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0\\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll";
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str));
```

That gives:

```
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp
```

[image: output]

If, for some reason, you're on Linux, and you pass through a path with Windows directory separators, then you can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str.Replace('\\', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)));
```

Comment: Why not simply use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel - I didn't know about that. Even better.

Comment: It gives `C:\Users\source\repos\InitiateService\InitiateService\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp`

Comment: @tRuEsAtM - No, I tested it before posting.

Comment: I am using .NET 6 that's why it gave me this output.

Comment: @tRuEsAtM - .NET 6 works perfectly fine. You're passing a windows path on a Linux machine - that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need

```
  var str = "C:\\Users\\source\\repos\\InitiateService\\InitiateService\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0\\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll";
       var fname =  System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str);
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.WriteLine(fname);
```

output

```
 C:\Users\source\repos\InitiateService\InitiateService\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll
 Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp
```

Comment: fname = C:\Users\source\repos\InitiateService\InitiateService\bin\Debug\net6.0\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp

Comment: @tRuEsAtM - if the code i show doesnt work right - are you on linux perhaps?

Comment: @tRuEsAtM You'll get that output if you run this code on Unix, because it uses the path separators of the current platform.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel - not if you put windows path separators in the string

Comment: For example, dotnetfiddle runs .NET 6 code on a Linux machine, so: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HkDpz0

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel - well i am surprised - so in fact it does not "use the path separator of the current platform"

Comment: @pm100 On Unix the separator is a forward slash. There are no forward slashes in the above path.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel you dot net fiddle has back slashes in it

Comment: Yes, it's a Windows path. `Path.GetFileName` determines what is the filename portion of the path using the directory separator(s) of the current platform. So on Windows the filename will be correctly identified because both `/` and `\ ` are used, but on Unix only `/` is considered.